# vuejs: vue-cli webpack template cannot resolve sass imports

Tags: webpack, vue.js, sass, vue-cli, vue-loader

I am having a problem with webpack/vue-cli when compiling styles from Sass with imports from node modules.

I cannot find a way to resolve `@imports` from `node_module` in sass correctly.

```css
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';  // not working, cannot resolve path (sass-loader syntax)
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';  //works, needs full relative paths
```

This seems to boil down to two issues:
 * sass-loader is not used to resolve imports from node_module (~module) despite being the loader configure by vue-cli for sass
 * postcss-import is used instead, but there is no mapping for the `node_module` folder, thus requiring a relative path. In this case, inner dependencies (for instance, fonts loaded via `url()` with a relative paths inside a style imported from node_modules) are not resolved.

Any ideas?
TIA

Answer (score 4):

Try installing `node-sass` and `sass-loader`

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader
```

Feel free to replace `npm` with `yarn` if you're using it.

---

Also, you can import bootstrap the following way

```
@import "~bootstrap";
```

Comment: this does not work when using the webpack template of vue-cli. I explicitly noted the syntax did not work since sass-loader is bypassed by postcss-import.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know you should not import a build css file into your sass.
Instead just import it in your main.js like that:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

Comment: this works, but the order in the built CSS is wrong (vue-cli uses webpack-text-extract-plugin).

to explain:
- chunks from .vue files (in sass)
- chunk from bootstrap import

The .vue files need to override some of bootstrap basic styles.